# Node js getting undefined when trying to read req.body json object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http-post

I'm sending a json object using curl (`curl http://localhost:8080/send -H "Content:Type: application/json" -d @data.json`) to my node js application.

After debugging it, using node-inspector, I seem to be getting the following in req.body:`{ "sender_id": 1 }: ""`, which is what I expect except for the trailing : "". Now, when I try to do `req.body["sender_id"]`, I get undefined. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: can you paste the data.json file, or an extract from this specific line ?

Comment: {"sender_id": 1} -- I've checked it with JSONLint so it should be good.

Comment: Try this : `curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"sender_id":1}' http://localhost:8080/send`